# How to restrict shapes to simple polygons in leaflet.draw?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I'm using `leaflet.draw` to draw polygons on a map. Even though in the options for `polygon` I set

```
allowIntersection: false, // Restricts shapes to simple polygons
```

I'm still able to draw self-intersecting polygons (as shown in the demo). How to fix that?

```js
// center of the map
var center = [-33.8650, 151.2094];

// Create the map
var map = L.map('map').setView(center, 6);

// Set up the OSM layer
L.tileLayer(
  'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Data © <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
  }).addTo(map);

// add a marker in the given location
L.marker(center).addTo(map);

// Initialise the FeatureGroup to store editable layers
var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(editableLayers);

var drawPluginOptions = {
  position: 'topleft',
  draw: {
    polygon: {
      allowIntersection: false, // Restricts shapes to simple polygons
      drawError: {
        color: '#e1e100', // Color the shape will turn when intersects
        message: '<strong>Oh snap!<strong> you can\'t draw that!' // Message that will show when intersect
      },
      shapeOptions: {
        color: '#97009c'
      }
    },
    // disable toolbar item by setting it to false
    polyline: false,
    circle: false, // Turns off this drawing tool
    rectangle: false,
    marker: false,
  },
  edit: {
    featureGroup: editableLayers, //REQUIRED!!
    remove: false
  }
};

// Initialise the draw control and pass it the FeatureGroup of editable layers
var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw(drawPluginOptions);
map.addControl(drawControl);

var editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(editableLayers);

map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
  var type = e.layerType,
    layer = e.layer;

  if (type === 'marker') {
    layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
  }

  editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.0-beta.2.rc.2/leaflet.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.0-beta.2.rc.2/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.2.3/leaflet.draw.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.2.3/leaflet.draw.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: This seems to be a bug related to the changes in Leaflet 1.0x. Intersections are detected correctly if you use Leaflet 0.7.7. While the master branch of Leaflet.Draw is being adapted for Leaflet 1.0, it does not correctly detect intersections either.

Comment: Did some digging around and figured out where the bug (probably) is in the Leaflet.Draw code, though I don't know how to fix it. Anyway, [it's reported on GitHub](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/525) now, so maybe there will be a fix sometime soon.